# Google App Script - loops not executing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a function that will iterate over every sheet until a given sheet. The function receives the name of that last sheet as an argument.

```
function getUntilMonthSavings(month) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var monthSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(month);
  var allSheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var sheetNumber = monthSheet.getIndex();

  var totalSavings=0;
  for (var i = 1; i < monthSheet; i++){
    totalSavings = totalSavings + allSheets[i].getRange("I20").getValue();
  }
  return totalSavings;
}
```

My problem is that what is returned is always 0. I've also returned **i** to check if it is being iterated, but it returns 1 even when the sheet index is greater than 1.

I'm sure to be doing some kind of basic blunder, but I'm quite at a loss as why this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

MonthSheet is an object and not something you can compare i to in your loop. You need the actual index of the sheet referred to.

Try:
    for (var i = 0; i < monthSheet.getIndex(); i += 1) {